# Question about ordinal exponentiation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, ordinals

I am having trouble on how to prove the following identity using ordinal arithmetic. Given a natural number $n > 1$:

$$n^{\omega^{\omega}} = \omega^{\omega^{\omega}}$$

I've tried to use the definition about exponentiation of ordinal numbers when the exponent is an ordinal limit, but I can't reach the result.

Any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: FYI, this is Exercise 2 on p. 320 of Sierpiński's 1965 book **Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers** and a solution is given on the same page. You don't say whether this is a random homework question, something that just happened to arise in some work you are doing, part of an extensive study of ordinal arithmetic you're doing for fun (I did this in the mid 1980s, for instance), or something else, but I mention Sierpiński's book in case whatever you're doing would benefit from a near-encyclopediac treatment of ordinal numbers and their arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

For example, we have $n^\omega=\omega$. Now proceeding further we get: $n^{\omega+1}=(n^\omega)\cdot n=\omega \cdot n$. Similarly: $n^{\omega+2}=n^{(\omega+1)+1}=(n^{\omega+1})\cdot n=(\omega \cdot n) \cdot n=\omega \cdot n^2$. Proceeding further: $n^{\omega+3}=n^{(\omega+2)+1}=(n^{\omega+2})\cdot n=(\omega \cdot n^2) \cdot n=\omega \cdot n^3$.

With an induction argument, we could show a general pattern. Now we get:
$n^{\omega \cdot 2}=\sup\{\omega,\omega \cdot n, \omega \cdot n^2, \omega \cdot n^3,.....\}=\omega^2$.

Similarly we would get $n^{\omega \cdot 3}=\omega^3$ and $n^{\omega \cdot 4}=\omega^4$. Following this further, we will get $n^{\omega^2}=\omega^\omega$.

---

Let's write $f(x)=\omega^x$ and $g(x)=n^x$ generally where $f$ and $g$ are "functions" from ordinals to ordinals. We can show a general equality here I think. That would be $f(N)=g(\omega \cdot N)$ for all ordinals $N \geq 1$. Loosely speaking, the reason is that $1$ step "forward" of the function $f$ is equivalent to $\omega$ steps forward of the function $g$ **[** to show this more formally, we would probably use transfinite induction probably, I think **]**. That's why this equality works.

**(i)** Plugging $N=1$ gives $f(1)=g(\omega \cdot 1)=g(\omega)$ which is same as $\omega^1=\omega=n^\omega$.

**(ii)** Plugging $N=2$ gives $f(2)=g(\omega \cdot 2)$ which is same as $\omega^2=n^{\omega \cdot 2}$.

**(iii)** Plugging $N=\omega$ gives $f(\omega)=g(\omega \cdot \omega)=g(\omega^2)$ which is same as $\omega^\omega=n^{\omega ^ 2}$.

**(iv)** Plugging $N=\omega^\omega$ gives $f(\omega^\omega)=g(\omega \cdot \omega^\omega)=g(\omega^\omega)$ which is same as $\omega^{(\omega^\omega)}=\omega^{\omega^\omega}=n^{(\omega ^ \omega)}=n^{\omega ^ \omega}$. This is the required identity.